# Serverpod unable to authenticate with postgres

Tags: postgresql, dart, backend, serverpod

I have a completely new clean project created with the cli, I.E. `serverpod create project_name`. But when I run the startup commands for the server, it fails to connect to the database.

I run

```
$ docker compose up --build --detach
$ dart bin/main.dart
```

The server continues to spam this error message, over and over again.

`Failed to connect to the database. Retrying in 10 seconds. PostgreSQLSeverity.fatal 28P01: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

I made sure I didn't run any docker containers from other projects, the postgres and redis containers comes from this new project but I still face this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I deleted and recreated the project manually but this left a docker volume pending with old data from the previous project.

To solve this you can simply run the following command from the server project folder.

`docker compose down -v`

This will kill and remove all containers, the -v flag will also make sure to delete any volumes attached to the containers.

The volume is recreated when you run `docker compose up --build --detach` with the correct data!

---

You can also remove the volume manually if you want by running

`docker volume ls`

This should print all current volumes, there should be a volume with the name `<project_name>_server_<project_name>_data` where project_name is the name of your project.

Then delete the volume by running

`docker volume rm <project_name>_server_<project_name>_data`

Make sure to kill the docker containers first or less you will get an error. I.E. `docker ps` and `docker kill <container_id>`